# Association OneToOne

Tags: extjs

Hello Gui i have questions about associations with ExtJS.

I have an application in which I manage the bugs reported by my customers.
Each bug is assigned to a customer.
In a grid I display all the declared bugs and I have a OneToOne association on the customer model

The json to load my store is:

```
[
{
    "bug_id": 1,
    "descriptif": "Proin eu mi. Nulla ac enim. In tempor, turpis nec euismod scelerisque, quam turpis adipiscing lorem, vitae mattis nibh ligula nec sem.",
    "customer": {
        "customer_id": 1,
        "firstname": "Josias",
        "lastname": "Reasun",
        "email": "jreasun0@uiuc.edu",
        "gender": "Female"
    }
},
{
    "bug_id": 2,
    "descriptif": "Nullam porttitor lacus at turpis. Donec posuere metus vitae ipsum. Aliquam non mauris.\n\nMorbi non lectus. Aliquam sit amet diam in magna bibendum imperdiet. Nullam orci pede, venenatis non, sodales sed, tincidunt eu, felis.\n\nFusce posuere felis sed lacus. Morbi sem mauris, laoreet ut, rhoncus aliquet, pulvinar sed, nisl. Nunc rhoncus dui vel sem.",
    "customer": {
        "customer_id": 1,
        "firstname": "Josias",
        "lastname": "Reasun",
        "email": "jreasun0@uiuc.edu",
        "gender": "Female"
    }
},
{
    "bug_id": 3,
    "descriptif": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Proin risus. Praesent lectus.",
    "customer": {
        "customer_id": 3,
        "firstname": "Zelig",
        "lastname": "Linneman",
        "email": "zlinneman2@github.com",
        "gender": "Male"
    }
},
{
    "bug_id": 4,
    "descriptif": "Quisque porta volutpat erat. Quisque erat eros, viverra eget, congue eget, semper rutrum, nulla. Nunc purus.\n\nPhasellus in felis. Donec semper sapien a libero. Nam dui.\n\nProin leo odio, porttitor id, consequat in, consequat ut, nulla. Sed accumsan felis. Ut at dolor quis odio consequat varius.",
    "customer": {
        "customer_id": 1,
        "firstname": "Josias",
        "lastname": "Reasun",
        "email": "jreasun0@uiuc.edu",
        "gender": "Female"
    }
},
{
    "bug_id": 5,
    "descriptif": "Phasellus in felis. Donec semper sapien a libero. Nam dui.",
    "customer": {
        "customer_id": 3,
        "firstname": "Zelig",
        "lastname": "Linneman",
        "email": "zlinneman2@github.com",
        "gender": "Male"
    }
}
```

]

The customer model is present for all bugs. So I have multiple duplicates of customer in my json.

Is a good practice or should I send a json with an array of bugs, an array of customers (distinct) and load this into 2 stores of my viewmodel.

Thank you for your opinions

Comment: This really comes down to the resource that's loading the data, and how you want to use it.  If your resource is something like `api/bugs`, then I don't see a problem with your data that's being returned here... you're returning a list of bugs and who reported it.  If, however, you wanted a list of users and their bugs, say `api/users`, then that to me would be a `hasMany` (list of user's bugs), but like I said, this comes down to how you're applying it.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thank for your response.

In fact, I'm just wondering if it's really a good use of associations this case. If I have 300 bugs assigned to the same contact, I will go up in my json 300 times the contact model with the same information to be able to display the name of the contact in a column of my grid